# Tomcat / Grails / Ubuntu website fails to render some capital letters with accent

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, grails, encoding

My grails application fails to render some capital letters when they have accent. Characters 'Á' and 'Í' aren't correctly coded. I.e: word "CARACTERÍSTICAS" is printed as "CARACTER�?STICAS". This only happens with the capital letters 'A' and 'I'. Letter 'O' is printed well with the accent.

Everything works well running on my windows development computer, but it fails when I put the application on the ubuntu server, so I think this is server related.

Server runs Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and Tomcat 8. I have checked that etc/default/tomcat contains:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

File application.yml sets the enconding to UFT-8

```
grails:    
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
```

I have also checked the connector at config.xml sets the URIEncoding to UTF-8:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443" />
```

The project resource file is also encoded in UTF-8

And finally, all my gsp files contain the line:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Edit 1:
Text source is "resource files" for translation. Using   to print.

I have ran out of ideas. Any help would be apreciated. Thanks in advance

Edit 2 - Solution: 
The resource file was in UFT-8. Once I changed it to ISO-8859-1 it worked. For some reason the resource files were in that format by default.

Comment: What is the source of this letters (Code, DB, GSP?) and what is they way you are outputting them (GSP, JSON?)

Comment: Source is "resource files", output is GSP

Comment: Using <g:message key="X"/> to print

Comment: Please edit the question, that this about the message sources.  Are you sure you are using the proper encoding for those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're saying in the comments (please edit them into your question) that this problem shows up with translated resources, I'm assuming that you have your resources in `Language.properties` files, and read them through ResourceBundles. These properties-files should be ISO-8859-1 encoded, as of Java standard. That most likely leads to `\u` encoded characters in the file.

Check the `native2ascii` tool from JDK.

Comment: It worked. The resource file was in UFT-8. Once I changed it to ISO-8859-1, translation works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I still ask myself why It worked on my computer (even though the file was in UTF) but not in the server. There must be something that overrides the behaviour